# Is it possible to conditionally use either `OrderBy` or `OrderByDescending` at the same time?

Tags: c#

Is it possible to conditionally use either `OrderBy` or `OrderByDescending` at the same time?

At the moment I have:

```
   public string[] GetCongregationListSortedByDate(bool bSortAscending)
   {
       try
       {
           List<string> listNames = new List<string>();
           if (bSortAscending)
           {
               var listCongregations = _CongregationData.CongregationDictionary
                                                           .OrderBy(x => x.Value.LastInvited).ToList();

               foreach (var oKVP in listCongregations)
               {
                   listNames.Add(oKVP.Value.Name);
               }
           }
           else
           {
               var listCongregations = _CongregationData.CongregationDictionary
                                                           .OrderByDescending(x => x.Value.LastInvited).ToList();

               foreach (var oKVP in listCongregations)
               {
                   listNames.Add(oKVP.Value.Name);
               }
           }

           return listNames.ToArray();
       }
       catch (Exception ex)
       {
           SimpleLog.Log(ex);
           return null;
       }
   }
```

This works but there is duplication of code. The only different bit is the sorting direction.

Comment: Couldn't you declare listCongregations before the if/else and then move the foreach var oKVP... out of it? That'd reduce some duplication

Comment: I can't declare a `var` type variable like that though. Unless I create an actual empty collection.

Comment: What are the data types of `_CongregationData.CongregationDictionary` and `x.Value.LastInvited`?

Comment: if you're against the overhead of an empty collection, You could do this without listNames and listCongregations: return the _CongregationData... but after the OrderBy parts, add .Select(c => c.Value.Name).ToArray(). Then you don't need the foreaches at all as a bonus.